# Lotus @command scripts for Reply/Reply All without attachment(s)

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I frequently use the "Reply with History without Attachment(s)" and "Reply to All with History without Attachment(s)" in Lotus Notes, and want to create buttons on the toolbar for these. Can anybody help with the @Command script for this?

I have tried using `@Command([Compose];"Reply With History")` but it replies only to sender, and ***with*** attachments.

Alternatively, is there way to assign a key sequence to a button? e.g. `Alt+A-R-R` / `Alt+A-P-R`

I am on Lotus Notes 8.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is

```
@Command([ComposeWithReference]; server : database ; form ; flags)
```

From Notes help: 
Flags:

Number. Optional. One or more of the following reference attributes. Combine attributes by adding them. Defaults to flags 3 plus 4. You must supply this parameter in Web applications.
...
16 -- Removes attachments, images, and other large objects from the reference copy, replacing them (except on the Web) with text statements in brackets.

Sample code:
    @Command([ComposeWithReference];"":"";"Reply"; 19) => flags 3 + 16

EDIT: 
If you custommize a mail file / mail template, add the following formular before the @Command:

```
@Environment("MailStEd";"9");
```

This makes sure you make a ReplyToAll

So the working code should look more or less like this (customize flags to match your needs):

```
@Environment("MailStEd";"9");
@Command([ComposeWithReference];"":"";"Reply"; 19)
```

Comment: I have a follow up question: Checking the documentation for @Command([ComposeWithReference]), I found this flag `4 -- Puts the Body of the main document in a collapsible section. Does not work on Web.` So I updated the script to use flag 20 instead of 19, but then the history disappeared altogether.

EDIT : Ok, I checked the example again and it turns out I have to use 3 + 4 + 16 = 23. So it appears
- 3 includes the history
- 4 makes it collapsible... and is useless without 3
- 16 removes attachments

Learn something new everyday :)

Comment: Thanks for the positive feedback. These flags sometimes behave a bit odd, but good to hear you worked it out :-)